# Running a .java file from a .jsp file

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to run my Mahout_Recommender.java file within my jsp file.

This is my .jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Recommendation Results</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my Mahout_Recommender.java file: 
        package mahout;

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
    import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
    import      org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.ThresholdUserNeighborhood;
    import       org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericUserBasedRecommender;
    import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.PearsonCorrelationSimilarity;
    import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
    import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.neighborhood.UserNeighborhood;
    import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.UserBasedRecommender;
    import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.UserSimilarity;

    /**
    * User-Based Recommender for Movies
    * 
    *
    */
    public class Movie_Recommender {
        //public static String [][] rows = new String[3884][6];
       public static void main (String [] args){
            int userID = 1; //I put this as a placeholder
            BasicConfigurator.configure();
            try{
               File movies = new File("movies.csv");
               String [][] rows = new String[3884][6];
               rows = fileRead(movies); //read in movie titles
               DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("ratings.csv")); 
               UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model); 
               UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, model); 
               UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
               ArrayList recommendations = null;
               recommendations = (ArrayList) recommender.recommend(userID, 3);                
               Object[] recs = recommendations.toArray();
               String movieTitles = " ";
               int movieID = 0;
               for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                  String s = recs[i].toString();
                  movieID = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(21, s.indexOf(",")));
                  movieTitles += "\n "+rows[movieID][1];
               }
                 System.out.println(recs[1]);
                 System.out.println("Your User-Based Recommendations are: ");
                 System.out.println(movieTitles);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e);
           }
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
             public static String[][] fileRead (File data) throws          FileNotFoundException{
             Scanner reader = new Scanner(data);
             String s = "";
             String [][] rows = new String[3884][6];
             int i = 0;
             while (i<3500){
                  s = reader.nextLine();

                  rows[i] = s.split(",");

               i++;
           }

          return rows;
         }

        }
```

How would I call the main method of the .java file inside my .jsp file?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a main method from another point.

You only need to call Movie_Recommender.main(null); in your servlet (null because you don't use args).

then in your jsp:

```
<% Movie_Recommender.main(null); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call it from .jsp likewise,

```
Movie_Recommender.main(new String[]{}); 
OR     
Movie_Recommender.main(null);
```

> Well honestly speaking, It's totally Bad idea to create main(...),
>   What are you trying to achieve? Even if you do that, by calling main()
>   as any other arbitrary method, or by invoking Runtime or something,
>   What you will achieve is a program running on server. What the client
>   would do with that.
>
> JSP/Servlet/Java Web programming is a request/response based stuff.
>
> If you want to compute something using that program and planning to
>   use the output as a response. Then why not include that particular
>   piece as business component or something and call that in a usual way.
>   May be in a separate thread, if its a long process, let the user
>   interact with the application and notify user once it is done.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you really want to execute the main method of that clas directly inside the JSP. but I think you simply can achieve it by **System** class like below:

```
int result = System.exec("/path/to/ClassName.java");
```

just an example how to execute the class and use your correct data type for the result variable.

If you need to pass parameters as well to the class, you can use the below post which provides a good answer [HERE!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675988/how-do-i-run-a-java-class-with-arguments-from-a-jsp-page)
hope it'll help !